# В строке буквы (символы) в другой кодировке?

Tags: php, кодировка

Всем привет.

Не могу понять как исправить.
В получаемых текстах попадаются слова с другой кодировкой что ли и\или символы какие?

Пример

```
температÑÐ°
```

Дальше уже так...

```
Ð¨Ð»Ð°Ð½Ð³
```

В итоге после этого летит кодировка всего текста который дальше.
Как-то можно исправить?

Данные получаю через file_get_contents в UTF8.
Так не все данные, а только часть.
Онлайн декодировщики показывают, что там уже ISO-8859-1.

Приходил в голову вариант разбивать весь текст на слова, определять кодировку и преобразовать в нужную. Или может тут что-то проще можно сделать?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: В получаемых откуда? И что значит «летит кодировка»?

Comment: @MAX в примере как-раз привел текст - "температ" написано нормально, дальше уже "ÑÐ°", то, что как-раз ломает все. В firefox подсвечивает там \u83, \u80.. После этого, весь текст примерно такой идет "Ð³ÑÐ°Ð´"